# Передача в контроллер сложной модели

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Существует модель имеющая связи многие ко многим. Необходимо отобразить форму так, чтобы в контроллере получить уже заполненную модель с одним связанным и заполненным объектом.

Модель:

```
public class Phrase
{
    public int PhraseId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }      
    public int Lang { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Phrase> translates { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Вы хотите коллекцию translates с клиента получать, предполагается, что пользователь введет несколько переводов для различных языков?

Comment: Да, но скорее несколько вариантов перевода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я вижу у вас дерево в модели. Модель содержит список таких же моделей. Для отображения такого рода модели я предлагаю использовать `EditorTemplates`.

- Создадим папку `EditorTemplates` во `Views\Shared`
- Создадим файл `Phrase.cshtml` в этой папке со следующим содержанием

  ```
  @model MVCReportViewer.Controllers.Phrase

  <li>
  @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.PhraseId)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Text)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Lang)

  @if (Model.Translates != null && Model.Translates.Any())
  {
      <ul>
          @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Translates)
      </ul>
  }
  </li>
  ```
- Тестовый контроллер метод контроллера `TestEditorTemplate`:

  ```
  public ActionResult TestEditorTemplate()
  {
      ViewData.Model = new List<Phrase>
      {
          new Phrase
          {
              PhraseId = 1,
              Text = "prase 1",
              Lang = 0,
              Translates = new List<Phrase>
              {
                  new Phrase
                  {
                      PhraseId = 11,
                      Text = "prase 1.1",
                      Lang = 1
                  },
                  new Phrase
                  {
                      PhraseId = 12,
                      Text = "prase 1.2",
                      Lang = 1,
                      Translates = new List<Phrase>
                      {
                          new Phrase
                          {
                              PhraseId = 121,
                              Text = "prase 1.2.1",
                              Lang = 1
                          },
                          new Phrase
                          {
                              PhraseId = 12,
                              Text = "prase 1.2.2",
                              Lang = 1
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          },
          new Phrase
          {
                              PhraseId = 2,
              Text = "prase 2",
              Lang = 3,
          }
      };
      return View();
  }
  ```

  - Тестовое представление `TestEditorTemplate.cshtml`

    ```
    @model IEnumerable<MVCReportViewer.Controllers.Phrase>

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "TestEditorTemplate";
    }


    <ul>
        @Html.EditorForModel()
    </ul>
    ```

Все, у нас все есть. Наш `EditorTemplate` сам сконструирует правильную разметку для того чтобы наша модель верно вернулось в контроллер, если мы заходим обернуть все это в форму. Я использовал хэлпер `EditorForModel`, но возможно использовать и `EditorFor`, если ваша модель является частью общей модели.

Более того - обратите внимание что нигде нет ни одного цикла. `EditorTemplate` применяется даже к коллекциям причем, расставляя верные name параметры в отрендереном `html`.

P.S. Обратите внимание, что я несколько изменил вашу `ViewModel`:

```
public class Phrase
{
    public int PhraseId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Lang { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Phrase> Translates { get; set; }
}
```

Не имеет смысл пользоваться коллекцией `ICollection` поскольку она имеет преимущество перед `IEnumerable` только в том случае если вы части изменяете значения в коллекции. А работа с **MVC** такова, что вы их только пишите внутрь, не изменяя. И принимаете из реквеста.

Comment: А как быть в том случае если модель не редактируется, а создается? Если из контроллера ничего  не приходит. В том случае если коллекция translates пуста и добавляется первый вариант? если @model.translates.any() == false?

Comment: Если вам нужно динамически поля добавлять - это уже с помощью js придется делать. Как советовал @beta-tank добавлять просто html в разметку. Но тут надо быть аккуратным в отношении правильности тегов и валидации на клиенте, если вы её используете.

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы связыватель модели понял, что вы передаёте коллекцию элементов, достаточно дать полям соответствующие названия. В Вашем случае, если добавить в представление создания объекта

```
<div>
    <label>Text 1:</label>
    <input class="text-box single-line" name="Translates[0].Text" type="text" value="" />
</div>
<div>
    <label>Lang 1:</label>
    <input class="text-box single-line" name="Translates[0].Lang" type="text" value="" />
</div>
<div>
    <label>Text 2:</label>
    <input class="text-box single-line" name="Translates[1].Text" type="text" value="" />
</div>
<div>
    <label>Lang 2:</label>
    <input class="text-box single-line" name="Translates[1].Lang" type="text" value="" />
</div>
```

Связыватель модели создаст два дополнительных объекта `Phrase` и добавит их в коллекцию `Translates`

Если необходимо, можно с помощью JavaScript генерировать нужное количество полей, в зависимости от требований пользователя.

Comment: А как это можно сделать с помощью @html.EditorFor?

Comment: @КонстантинГалиахметов , с помощью него сделать не получится, потому что этот хэлпер сам задаёт свойства `id` и `name` для элемента. Если количество элементов заранее известно, создайте частичное представление, моделью которого является класс, включающий имя коллекции и порядковый номер элемента. В этом представлении генерируйте желаемую разметку для нужных полей, подставляя в `name` имя коллекции и номер. Это упростит создание вложенных элементов.

Comment: @beta-tank Можно это сделать с помощью EditorFor, не вводите людей в заблуждение. можно даже переопределить, как это будет выглядеть с помощью EditorTemplates.

Comment: @teovankot тогда напишите пожалуйста пример. я, да и скорее всего автор будем рады узнать этот метод

Comment: @bata-tank пожалуйста

Comment: @teovankot не знал, что так можно, спасибо за пример